# Small visual bug in "Job Recommendations" in the profile page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

In the profile, there is this section:

[image: Job Recommendations]

But when you click on "Show Jobs", it shows like this:
[image: Edit preferences.Minimize jobs]

The "Edit preferences." and "Minimize Jobs" seem to be overlapping:
[image: Overlapped text]

Confirmed this is not resolution-dependent by resizing the browser to 2400px.
It isn't cache, as it has been cleared. Refreshing doesn't make it go away as well.

I'm running on Linux Mint 20, using Google Chrome 84.0.4147.135 (x64).